# What is the meaning of getch()==13

Tags: c, ascii, getch

The source code is given bellow, What does the line of **if(getch()==13)** means..
int main()
{

```
int a[4],approx[4],b[4],i=0;  
int arr[4][6],sarr[4][6];  
initialize(a);  
encoding(a,arr);  

while(i<5)  

{  

            if(i==0)  
    {  
        while((selection(a,approx,sarr,arr,b))==0)  
        {  

            initialize(a);  
            encoding(a,arr);  
        }  
    }  
    else  
        selection(a,approx,sarr,arr,b);  
    crossover(sarr,a,b,arr);  
    if(getch()==13)  

    mutation(arr);  
    evaluate(arr,a);  
    getch();  
    i++;  
}  

getch();
```

}
What does the line of code **if(getch()==13)** means..

Comment: ASCII 13 == carriage return. getch() is get a single character of input from the user.  Basically checking if the user hit Enter.

Comment: Ooo, wouldn't that only work on DOS systems with `\r\n` newlines?

Comment: Yes, and getch() is also non-standard. If this doesn't currently work on your system, I'd recommend trying to replace the line with getchar()==10

Comment: Or even better, with `getchar()=='\n'` for readability's sake

Answer (score 0):

The line

```
if (getch() == 13)
```

means whether the value taken as input from `getch()` is equal to 13 or not.

Note -
getch() is a non-standard functions defined in conio.h header library, mostly used in turbo C/dev C++ environement. getchar() is standard functions defined in C standard and they can be used in all environments

Comment: True, but what does _that_ mean?

Comment: getch() is a non-standard functions defined in conio.h header library, mostly used in turbo C/dev C++ environement. getchar() is standard functions defined in C standard and they can be used in all environments.

Answer (score 0):

The C library function int `getchar()` gets a character (an unsigned char) from `stdin`. Here the line `if (getch() == 13)` checks if the user has entered a carriage return character (13 is the ascii value of CR).

Comment: the code is like- **if(getch()==13)  **
  
  **mutation(arr);**  
  **getch();  **
   can you plz elaborate how its working? @VHS

Comment: I just saw your edits. All the `if` condition does is call a function call `mutation()` if the user has entered a carriage return. There's nothing special.

Answer (score -1):

the return value of `getchar()` is equal ASCII

Comment: That is implementation specified whether or not it is ASCII. In this case it is, but this is not really helpful.